R8 full mode in AGP8 breaks flutter_local_notifications
After upgrading AGP to version 8.4, zonedSchedule notifications causes app to crash
Use this minimally altered example project: NotificationsSample

Run Pixel 7 API 33 emulator from Android Studio Jellyfish 2023.3.1 (don't think the version matters, but just in case)
Run the project in VS Code on the above emulator
Click Show plain notification with payload button. This works OK.
Now click Schedule notification to appear in 5 seconds button.
App crashes with below error:

E/AndroidRuntime( 7543): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 7543): Process: com.example.notifications, PID: 7543
E/AndroidRuntime( 7543): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver: java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing type parameter.
E/AndroidRuntime( 7543):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4315)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7543):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleReceiver(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7543):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2153)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7543):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7543):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7543):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7543):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7543):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7543):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7543):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7543): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing type parameter.
E/AndroidRuntime( 7543):    at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.getSuperclassTypeParameter(TypeToken.java:84)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7543):    at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.<init>(TypeToken.java:62)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7543):    at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver$1.<init>(ScheduledNotificationReceiver.java:58)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7543):    at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver.onReceive(ScheduledNotificationReceiver.java:58)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7543):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4306)

Adding below line to gradle.properties file fixes the problem:
android.enableR8.fullMode = false

But this seems a very radical workaround. Any better ideas?
Issue is reproduced in this project:
NotificationsSample
